# Macro substitution fail in GCC 4.7 / Clang 3.2

Tags: c++, boost, macros, clang, c-preprocessor

I've been successfully using some "popular" macros in a Windows 7 + VisualStudio 2012 environment. Last week I wanted to port the project to Linux (no platform dependent code, small codebase). Making the C++ code to build was easy enough, I can't the same for the macros, though.

I've put together this simple test:

```
/// concatenates tokens, even when the tokens are macros themselves
#define PP_JOIN_HELPER_HELPER(_0, _1)    _0##_1
#define PP_JOIN_HELPER(_0, _1)       PP_JOIN_HELPER_HELPER(_0, _1)
#define PP_JOIN_IMPL(_0, _1)         PP_JOIN_HELPER(_0, _1)

#define PP_JOIN_2(_0, _1)                                  PP_JOIN_IMPL(_0, _1)
#define PP_JOIN_3(_0, _1, _2)                                PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_2(_0, _1), _2)
#define PP_JOIN_4(_0, _1, _2, _3)                              PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_3(_0, _1, _2), _3)
#define PP_JOIN_5(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4)                            PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_4(_0, _1, _2, _3), _4)
#define PP_JOIN_6(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5)                          PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_5(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4), _5)
#define PP_JOIN_7(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6)                        PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_6(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5), _6)
#define PP_JOIN_8(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7)                      PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_7(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6), _7)
#define PP_JOIN_9(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8)                    PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_8(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7), _8)
#define PP_JOIN_10(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9)                 PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_9(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8), _9)
#define PP_JOIN_11(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10)                PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_10(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9), _10)
#define PP_JOIN_12(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11)             PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_11(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10), _11)
#define PP_JOIN_13(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12)          PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_12(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11), _12)
#define PP_JOIN_14(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13)       PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_13(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12), _13)
#define PP_JOIN_15(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14)      PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_14(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13), _14)
#define PP_JOIN_16(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15)   PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_15(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14), _15)


/// chooses a value based on a condition
#define PP_IF_0(t, f)      f
#define PP_IF_1(t, f)      t
#define PP_IF(cond, t, f)    PP_JOIN_2(PP_IF_, PP_TO_BOOL(cond))(t, f)


/// converts a condition into a boolean 0 (=false) or 1 (=true)
#define PP_TO_BOOL_0 0
#define PP_TO_BOOL_1 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_2 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_3 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_4 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_5 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_6 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_7 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_8 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_9 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_10 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_11 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_12 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_13 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_14 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_15 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_16 1

#define PP_TO_BOOL(x)    PP_JOIN_2(PP_TO_BOOL_, x)


/// Returns 1 if the arguments to the variadic macro are separated by a comma, 0 otherwise.
#define PP_HAS_COMMA(...)              PP_HAS_COMMA_EVAL(PP_HAS_COMMA_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0))
#define PP_HAS_COMMA_EVAL(...)           __VA_ARGS__
#define PP_HAS_COMMA_ARGS(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, ...) _16


/// Returns 1 if the argument list to the variadic macro is empty, 0 otherwise.
#define PP_IS_EMPTY(...)                           \
  PP_HAS_COMMA                               \
  (                                     \
    PP_JOIN_5                              \
    (                                   \
      PP_IS_EMPTY_CASE_,                       \
      PP_HAS_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__),                   \
      PP_HAS_COMMA(PP_IS_EMPTY_BRACKET_TEST __VA_ARGS__),     \
      PP_HAS_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__ (~)),                 \
      PP_HAS_COMMA(PP_IS_EMPTY_BRACKET_TEST __VA_ARGS__ (~))    \
    )                                   \
  )

#define PP_IS_EMPTY_CASE_0001      ,
#define PP_IS_EMPTY_BRACKET_TEST(...)  ,


// PP_VA_NUM_ARGS() is a very nifty macro to retrieve the number of arguments handed to a variable-argument macro.
// unfortunately, VS 2010 still has this preprocessor bug which treats a __VA_ARGS__ argument as being one single parameter:
// https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521844/variadic-macro-treating-va-args-as-a-single-parameter-for-other-macros#details
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
# define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, N, ...)  N
# define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_REVERSE_SEQUENCE     16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
# define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_LEFT (
# define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_RIGHT )
# define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS(...)           PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_LEFT __VA_ARGS__, PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_REVERSE_SEQUENCE PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_RIGHT
#else
# define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS(args...)           PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(args, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
# define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, N, ...)  N
#endif

// PP_NUM_ARGS correctly handles the case of 0 arguments
#define PP_NUM_ARGS(...)               PP_IF(PP_IS_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__), 0, PP_VA_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))


// PP_PASS_ARGS passes __VA_ARGS__ as multiple parameters to another macro, working around the following bug:
// https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521844/variadic-macro-treating-va-args-as-a-single-parameter-for-other-macros#details
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
# define PP_PASS_ARGS_LEFT (
# define PP_PASS_ARGS_RIGHT )
# define PP_PASS_ARGS(...)             PP_PASS_ARGS_LEFT __VA_ARGS__ PP_PASS_ARGS_RIGHT
#else
# define PP_PASS_ARGS(...)             (__VA_ARGS__)
#endif


/// Expand any number of arguments into a list of operations called with those arguments
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_0(op)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_1(op, a1)                                     op(a1, 0)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_2(op, a1, a2)                                   op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_3(op, a1, a2, a3)                                 op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_4(op, a1, a2, a3, a4)                               op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_5(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)                             op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_6(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6)                           op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_7(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7)                         op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_8(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8)                       op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_9(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9)                     op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7) op(a9, 8)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_10(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10)                 op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7) op(a9, 8) op(a10, 9)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_11(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11)                op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7) op(a9, 8) op(a10, 9) op(a11, 10)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_12(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12)             op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7) op(a9, 8) op(a10, 9) op(a11, 10) op(a12, 11)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_13(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13)          op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7) op(a9, 8) op(a10, 9) op(a11, 10) op(a12, 11) op(a13, 12)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_14(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14)       op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7) op(a9, 8) op(a10, 9) op(a11, 10) op(a12, 11) op(a13, 12) op(a14, 13)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_15(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15)      op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7) op(a9, 8) op(a10, 9) op(a11, 10) op(a12, 11) op(a13, 12) op(a14, 13) op(a15, 14)
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS_16(op, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16)   op(a1, 0) op(a2, 1) op(a3, 2) op(a4, 3) op(a5, 4) op(a6, 5) op(a7, 6) op(a8, 7) op(a9, 8) op(a10, 9) op(a11, 10) op(a12, 11) op(a13, 12) op(a14, 13) op(a15, 14) op(a16, 15)

#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS(op, ...)    PP_JOIN_2(PP_EXPAND_ARGS_, PP_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) PP_PASS_ARGS(op, __VA_ARGS__)

/// Turn any legal C++ expression into nothing
#define UNUSED_IMPL(symExpr, n) , (void)sizeof(symExpr)
#define UNUSED(...) (void)sizeof(true) PP_EXPAND_ARGS PP_PASS_ARGS(UNUSED_IMPL, __VA_ARGS__)
/// stringizes a string, even macros
#define PP_STRINGIZE_HELPER(token)   #token
#define PP_STRINGIZE(token)          PP_STRINGIZE_HELPER(token)

#define TEST_CONDITION(condition, a, ...) (condition) ? UNUSED(a) : UNUSED(__VA_ARGS__)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = 3, b = 4, c = 5;
    //UNUSED(a);
    TEST_CONDITION(true, a, b, c);
}
```

The macro substition in the end works fine in VS 2012, but it GCC and Clang fail.

Running `clang -E macro.cpp` creates this output:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = 3, b = 4, c = 5;

    (true) ? (void)sizeof(true) PP_EXPAND_ARGS (UNUSED_IMPL, a) : (void)sizeof(true) PP_EXPAND_ARGS (UNUSED_IMPL, b, c);

}
```

failing to expand PP_EXPAND_ARGS.

Running `clang macro.cpp` gives this errors:

```
macro.cpp:141:5: error: expected ':'
    TEST_CONDITION(true, a, b, c);
    ^
macro.cpp:135:57: note: expanded from macro 'TEST_CONDITION'
#define TEST_CONDITION(condition, a, ...) (condition) ? UNUSED(a) : UNUSED(__VA_ARGS__)
                                                        ^
macro.cpp:128:44: note: expanded from macro 'UNUSED'
#define UNUSED(args...) (void)sizeof(true) PP_EXPAND_ARGS PP_PASS_ARGS(UNUSED_IMPL, args)
                                           ^
macro.cpp:141:5: note: to match this '?'
macro.cpp:135:55: note: expanded from macro 'TEST_CONDITION'
#define TEST_CONDITION(condition, a, ...) (condition) ? UNUSED(a) : UNUSED(__VA_ARGS__)
                                                      ^
macro.cpp:141:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UNUSED_IMPL'
    TEST_CONDITION(true, a, b, c);
    ^
macro.cpp:135:57: note: expanded from macro 'TEST_CONDITION'
#define TEST_CONDITION(condition, a, ...) (condition) ? UNUSED(a) : UNUSED(__VA_ARGS__)
                                                        ^
macro.cpp:128:72: note: expanded from macro 'UNUSED'
#define UNUSED(args...) (void)sizeof(true) PP_EXPAND_ARGS PP_PASS_ARGS(UNUSED_IMPL, args)
                                                                       ^
macro.cpp:101:45: note: expanded from macro 'PP_PASS_ARGS'
# define PP_PASS_ARGS(args...)             (args)
                                            ^
2 errors generated.
```

basically telling me that UNUSED_IMPL is not declared, when it is.

I don't understand why it isn't working and why it tells me that the UNUSED_IMPL macro is not declared.

Comment: It isn't saying that the UNUSED_IMPL macro is not declared, it is telling you that after macro expansion it still has UNUSED_IMPL somewhere, and no variable or function with that name is declared. Visual studio is known to have a fairly non-standard preprocessor, you may need to add some more indirections in your macros.

Comment: UNUSED_IMPL is defined when it is followed by an argument list, but not without, so maybe passing it by name is broken somehow. What does your final preprocessed source look like? Maybe if there were another layer of macros it would process better?

Comment: PP_EXPAND_ARGS is supposed to pass the list of arguments to UNUSED_IMPL. I could try adding more indirections and see what happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the macro PP_PASS_ARGS:

```
# define PP_PASS_ARGS(args...)             (args)
```

When left out of UNUSED and PP_EXPAND_ARGS macros everything works fine:

```
#define PP_EXPAND_ARGS(op, args...)    PP_JOIN_2(PP_EXPAND_ARGS_, PP_NUM_ARGS(args))(op, args)
#define UNUSED(args...) (void)sizeof(true) PP_EXPAND_ARGS(UNUSED_IMPL, args)
```

I don't know why that works with VisualStudio's preprocessor and not with GCC's and Clang's. And I haven't tried to remove the PP_PASS_ARGS macro under VisualStudio yet, to see if I can get rid of it altogether.

EDIT: I tried removing the PP_PASS_ARGS macro under VisualSutio, but it didn't work.

Comment: From some discussions in Boost mailing lists related to Boost.PP, I recollect that Visual Studio C++ compilers and their preprocessors are not entirely conforming and expand macros wrongly. It is likely that both Clang and GCC are correct in rejecting your code.